# Punctuation 'but'

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

Is there too much punctuation in this sentence?  Which is more acceptable?

*Often, I think they still should, but, still, the premium’s given to these bigger sales.

Often, I think they still should, but, still the premium’s given to these bigger sales.

Often, I think they still should but, still, the premium’s given to these bigger sales.*

The first sentence seems like too much punctuation, but is probably 'technically correct'. I'd plump for the third one if I had to, but I want it to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: Correcting the punctuation of a sentence whose meaning is unclear might not be helpful. How wedded are you to using the word "still" twice?

Comment: I'm doing my best with the text - it's non-negotiable as it's a verbatim transcript.

Comment: OK :-) This is how we would *say* it, so it might be the clearest way to punctuate it: **Often I think they still should, but still, the premium’s given to these bigger sales.** BUT if the second "still" means "after all this time," it needs to be moved to before "given": **Often I think they still should, but the premium’s *still* given to these bigger sales.**

Comment: Or, if that second "still" means "after all this time" and you really *can't* change the word-order, you might italicize the second "still": "Often I think they still should, but *still* the premium’s given to these bigger sales."

Comment: Thank you! I will go with ... should, but still, the... :)

Comment: I think the minimum punctuation necessary to ensure the intended meaning of the sentence is all that is necessary. As my fourth or fifth grade teacher would say in reference to punctuation - “If in doubt, leave it out.”